# Проблемы с подключением по ssh. Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, администрирование, unix

Есть комп (ubuntu 16.04), ip:

```
10.9.8.1
```

ip компа (ubuntu 16.04) к которому хочу подключится:

```
10.9.8.2
```

Пингуясь получаю:

```
PING 10.9.8.2 (10.9.8.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.9.8.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.9.8.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.9.8.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

ifconfig моего компа (скопировал необходимое):

```
ib0       Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr <убрано>
          inet addr:10.9.8.1  Bcast:10.9.8.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:65520  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:256 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Вопрос, почему я не могу подключится по ssh к компу, статусы: networking, opensm работают

Comment: А где расположен второй комп?

Comment: там же где первый(в одной сети), он по меланоксу соединен

Comment: прикладывайте вывод `$ ip a; ip r; ip ru; ip r get 10.9.8.2`

Comment: ip a (толкьо ib0):
5: ib0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 65520 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 256
    link/infiniband 80:00:02:48:ff:90:00:00:00:00:00:00:50:6b:4b:03:00:5b:03:22 brd 00:ff:ff:ef:ff:19:40:1b:ff:ff:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.9.8.1/28 brd 10.9.8.15 scope global ib0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: ip r:
default via 10.x.x.1 dev eno2 onlink 
10.0.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.1 
10.9.8.0/28 dev ib0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.9.8.1 linkdown 
10.x.x.0/24 dev eno2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.x.x.2

Comment: ip ru 
0: from all lookup local 
32766: from all lookup main 
32767: from all lookup default

Comment: ip r get 10.9.8.2
10.9.8.2 dev ib0  src 10.9.8.1 
    cache

Comment: Может лучше эти выхлопы в вопрос добавить? Глаза слезятся.